# Is there a limit on the number on named pipes that can be created on a Linux machine?

Tags: named-pipes

And if so, how do we increase it - the named pipes are created using mkfifo command -

Comment: If you are suggesting creating so many that you would worry about running into a limit, I would suggest that your system architecture is wrong! You shouldn't need more than a handful.

Answer (score 2):

Since everything in linux is a file and fifi named pipes are files, i think there's no maximum number of named pipes ...

However it depend if you want to create a huge number of named pipes in the same directory could be a limit that that is a constraint of some File system ...

Answer (score 1):

Each end of the pipe uses a [file descriptor](http://www.cs.fredonia.edu/zubairi/s2k2/csit431/pipes.html).  On your system check out [/proc/sys/fs/file-max](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/condorg/linux_scalability.html).